# Windows 7 checkdisk deleted my folders. Can someone please help me recover it (am desperate)?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

I have a windows 7 system. Restarted the system and it said the HDD might need a disk check. So I let it continue. The checkdisk completed. But as I log in I see it has deleted a folder and all the internal files. I was working on just one of the files yesterday. It doesn't seem to have moved the files to some 'found.xxx' folder (I checked). I tried to recover the event log and here it is:

```
*"Level Date and Time   Source  Event ID    Task Category
Information 10/7/2022 12:45:03 PM   Microsoft-Windows-Wininit   1001    None    "
Checking file system on H:
The type of the file system is NTFS.
Volume label is - LAPTOP C.
One of your disks needs to be checked for consistency. You
may cancel the disk check, but it is strongly recommended
that you continue.
Windows will now check the disk.                         
CHKDSK is verifying files (stage 1 of 3)...
The attribute of type 0x80 and instance tag 0x5 in file 0x8
has allocated length of 0x356dcff000 instead of 0x53eaf31000.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (128, $Bad)
from file record segment 8.
  899584 file records processed.                                         
File verification completed.
Deleting orphan file record segment 88544.
Deleting orphan file record segment 88545.
Deleting orphan file record segment 88546.
Deleting orphan file record segment 88547.
  1532 large file records processed.                                   
  0 bad file records processed.                                     
  0 EA records processed.                                           
  6 reparse records processed.                                      
CHKDSK is verifying indexes (stage 2 of 3)...
The object id index entry in file 0x19 points to file 0x159e3
but the file has no object id in it.
Deleting an index entry from index $O of file 25.
**Index entry -- Holi of index $I30 in file 0x6bb8 points to unused file 0x159e0.
Deleting index entry -- Holi in index $I30 of file 27576.
Index entry --HOLI~1 of index $I30 in file 0x6bb8 points to unused file 0x159e0.
Deleting index entry --HOLI~1 in index $I30 of file 27576.**
Index entry Computational Complexity_ The Letter.html of index $I30 in file 0xe874 points to unused file 0x159e1.
Deleting index entry Computational Complexity_ The Letter.html in index $I30 of file 59508.
**Index entry - PSPACE of index $I30 in file 0x109de points to unused file 0x159e3.
Deleting index entry - PSPACE in index $I30 of file 68062.**
Index entry KfBtimSXNyN.css of index $I30 in file 0x124d7 points to unused file 0x159e2.
Deleting index entry KfBtimSXNyN.css in index $I30 of file 74967.
Index entry KFBTIM~1.CSS of index $I30 in file 0x124d7 points to unused file 0x159e2.
Deleting index entry KFBTIM~1.CSS in index $I30 of file 74967.
  997656 index entries processed.                                        
Index verification completed.
CHKDSK is scanning unindexed files for reconnect to their original directory.
  24 unindexed files scanned.                                        
CHKDSK is recovering remaining unindexed files.
  24 unindexed files recovered.                                      
CHKDSK is verifying security descriptors (stage 3 of 3)...
  899584 file SDs/SIDs processed.                                        
Cleaning up 1 unused index entries from index $SII of file 0x9.
Cleaning up 1 unused index entries from index $SDH of file 0x9.
Cleaning up 1 unused security descriptors.
Security descriptor verification completed.
  49037 data files processed.                                           
CHKDSK is verifying Usn Journal...
  38669152 USN bytes processed.                                            
Usn Journal verification completed.
Correcting errors in the Bad Clusters File.
Correcting errors in the master file table's (MFT) BITMAP attribute.
Correcting errors in the Volume Bitmap.
Windows has made corrections to the file system.
 440749055 KB total disk space.
 431714312 KB in 766630 files.
    257996 KB in 49040 indexes.
         0 KB in bad sectors.
   1020239 KB in use by the system.
     65536 KB occupied by the log file.
   7756508 KB available on disk.
      4096 bytes in each allocation unit.
 110187263 total allocation units on disk.
   1939127 allocation units available on disk.
Internal Info:
00 ba 0d 00 40 72 0c 00 ae a3 0f 00 00 00 00 00  ....@r..........
10 42 00 00 06 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  .B..............
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 3f 00 10 e3 45 00  ..........?...E.*
"
```

PSPACE is the name of the folder I was working in (it had multiple files and subfolders). Other two folders -- holi and --HOLI~1 were seemingly also deleted.

Can someone please tell me how I recover these files. This was my research project and I was foolish enough not to have a backup. Can someone please help. I am in panic and desperate.

Comment: The hard drive is dying, only a professional recovery service will have a chance in recovering you data.

Answer (score 4):

> I was foolish enough not to have a backup. Can someone please help. I
> am in panic and desperate.    ..

This is indeed a very tough lesson to learn.

CHKDSK isolates files and sectors because of damage and corruption. So there was some other issue to begin with.

Once CHKDSK has done its work and with the errors you have shown in your log, there is not much way to recover the data.

You can remove the disk and take it to a local recovery agency for an estimate if data can be recovered and then the estimated cost.

In future, you need to back up your work to another computer or to a very good USB drive.

Comment: If we assume chkdsk deletes files and folders by toggling an 'in use / not in use bit' as is the case with 'normal' file deletions then data is not fundamentally unrecoverable. If we assume NTFS and user powers down drive, pretty good results may be achieved.

Comment: Biggest factor would be, is drive the drive the OS resides on as it is constantly written to. And is this HDD or SSD. If SSD then TRIM may be the factor that renders data unrecoverable by any software-only means. A data recovery lab may be able to provided drive is removed from power ASAP.

Comment: A Windows 7 machine most likely had a HDD because of age. This is why I suggested a local recovery agency.

Comment: Local data recovery may indeed be best option specially seen the fact it was research project and OP hasn't got a clue (no offense to OP intended). Most important then, POWER DOWN DRIVE.

Comment: thank you to you both. I am searching for a local data recovery dest. P.S. its a HDD and it wasn't the primary OS drive and as correctly pointed old system thus hdd.  thank you again..

Comment: @TheoryQuest1 "HDD and it wasn't the primary OS drive" Oh that in general means your chances to recover the data just increased. If you intend to DIY clone the drive as a first step using for example HDDSuperClone from a Linux live USB stick.

Answer (score 2):

Rule number 1 : The disk in question should not be changed any more
in any way, since that may destroy data needed for recovery.
If this is your system disk, extract it from the computer, put inside
an enclosure, and try to recover your files on another computer.

You should then run recovery programs on the disk and hope to find
your files. Note that, even if found, the files may be truncated or
corrupted in some way.
And never write the recovered files to the disk being recovered.

I recommend the
[MiniTool Data Recovery Software Free](https://www.minitool.com/data-recovery-software/free-for-windows.html),
as I had good results with it.

For alternate products, see
[Best data recovery software of 2022: paid and free file recovery solutions](https://www.techradar.com/best/best-data-recovery-software).

If really desperate, you could use a commercial disk data recovery service,
as they employ better and much costlier software than the above.

Comment: With regards to 'best' file recovery software, I'd never rely on such websites. Maybe consider file recovery software most frequently used for logical data recovery in data recovery labs. These are probably R-Studio, UFS Explorer, ReclaiMe (PRO) and DMDE. I'd always opt for a consumer version for one of those.

Comment: I am right now trying Minitool to see if that works.. I have heard about UFS so i will give it a try too.. hoping for the best :(

Comment: Joep van Steen, is ReclaiMe your software or does it code rely on code that you programmed? If yes, you should be so fair to disclose it.

Comment: harrymc, stating " try to recover your files on another computer." is not enough. It should be an operating system like linux that does not necessarily automounts partitions on a disk. Can't provide the source, but as far as I know even without a pending write job  a windows machine writes on a NTFS disk/partition during a mount process.

Comment: @r2d3: There's no problem with mounting, which anyway is required for recovery, as long as no writing is done. I have done my share of recovering disks and this is no problem.

Comment: harrymc, mounting a partition is only necessary if you want to access a partition on file level. Faced with a broken file system this is the last thing you want to do. Furthermore, on NTFS windows will write the accessed time stamp of a file when accessing files - not a good idea for data recovery even though this transaction will not require additional space.

Comment: @r2d3 it isn't.

Comment: I captured Windows mounting a partition in this video. https://youtu.be/mW7eGh8P24M